what is the best experience for URL inputs?
I am designing some input which users should enter some links, I want to know what is the best way for these kind of inputs for users to show them doesn't need to enter "https://" and we will fill this part for u our self

If you're designing this feature for tech-savvy users, it's enough to include a brief note above the input fields or in the input label indicating that only the domain name is required. For less tech-savvy users, consider adding the URL scheme to ensure clarity.
Example

On the other hand, if you're designing this feature for non tech-savvy users, more guidance will be needed, like including instructions on how to copy the URL and trim the protocol part. Keep in mind that in some browsers, the protocol might be invisible when copying the URL, but it will still be included when pasted.
Example

It's important to mention that the feature should be designed to allow users to paste URLs with or without the protocol. It's pretty easy to trim or add the protocol on client or on server side if necessary.

An improvement would be to provide faster feedback message to the user if the URL is in invalid format, typically at the client side instead of server.
